# 525 m nvidia grapic card is not work in Linux

Tags: nvidia

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How well do laptops with Nvidia Optimus work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36930/how-well-do-laptops-with-nvidia-optimus-work)

i have dell dell **inspiron 15r** and company give the windows 7 64 bit os. i have 1GB 525m nvidia  graphic card which work in windows very well but when i install the ubuntu 10.10 then graphic card is not work.

ubuntu 10.10 give that message that i have nvidia graphic card  which not active you want to active. when i say ok then its download driver from the net and then install it when restart computer then graphic terminal is not working other terminal is work well. i have not idea why that happen plz help me ?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to download and install the driver from nvidia directly. Following steps are necessary:

1. Download the latest linux driver for your card from [Nvidia](http://www.nvidia.co.uk/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-uk)

store it in a folder, e.g. /tmp/NVIDIA###.run

Close all running programs and save all changes to any open documents!!!

1. Switch to plain text console (CTRL + ALT + F1) and log in as normal user
2. make the .run file executrable with:

   chmod +x /tmp/NVIDIA###.run
3. stop the graphical window manager:

   sudo initctl stop gdm
4. install the driver:

   /tmp/NVIDIA###.run

Follow the instructions - warnings might appear but usually can be considered harmless

1. restart the graphical window manager:

   sudo initctl start gdm
2. switch back to workspace by pressing CTRL + ALT + F7 or F8

(replaye NVIDIA### by the original filename of the file downloaded)s