# Monitor not detected - low resolution only

Tags: xorg, monitor, lightdm

I just installed Ubuntu 11.1 on my desktop pc. It was a clean install, no upgrading.
I have a Samsung Syncmaster BX2450 connected to the PC.

My problem is that I cannot make Ubuntu recognize my monitor - which is capable of more than 1024. I ran a shut down of lightdm, and ran sudo X -configure, but it gave me a "configuration failed". Nothing seems to work - any ideas?

VESA: GF119 Board - 13100000

```
xx@xxx:~$ lspci -nn |grep VGA
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: nVidia Corporation GT520 [GeForce GT520] [10de:1040] (rev a1)

xx@xxx:~$ xrandr -q
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 640 x 480, current 1024 x 768, maximum 1024 x 768
default connected 1024x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768       61.0* 
   800x600        61.0  
   640x480        60.0
```

- I downloaded the driver directly, installed it according to Michael K's answer. But I am back to square one - the screen gets to the purple start color - and locks. Any suggestions as what to do now?

I would very much like to use 1920 x 1200

Comment: I suggest to try the proprietary driver from NVidia!

Comment: I tried that during my first installation attempt. This meant that I could not access the gui at all.

Comment: no, try it with the driver downloaded directly from nvidia. I never had troubles that way. I described the installation procedure here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/80121/525-m-nvidia-grapic-card-is-not-work-in-linux

Comment: what resolution would you like to use ? 1920 x 1200 ? 1440x900 ?

Comment: what's your output of `glxinfo | grep render` ?

Answer (score 2):

I had a different Samsung Syncmaster monitor, and it was unable to correctly communicate its native resolution to the OS. The solution is to write a `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` that specifies the desired screen resolution. Mine looks like this when using the nvidia binary driver:

```
# Need a xorg.conf because the native resolution of the SyncMaster 920N
# monitor is misdetected. Plus I'm using the binary nVidia driver.

Section "Monitor"
        Identifier      "SyncMaster920N"
        Modeline        "1280x1024@60" 109.00 1280 1368 1496 1712 1024 1027 1034 1063 -hsync +vsync
EndSection

Section "Screen"
        Identifier      "Default Screen"
        Device          "GeForce9600GT"
        Monitor         "SyncMaster920N"
        DefaultDepth    24
        SubSection "Display"
                Depth           24
                Modes           "1280x1024@60"
        EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Module"
        Load    "glx"
EndSection

Section "Device"
        Identifier      "GeForce9600GT"
        Driver          "nvidia"
        Option          "NoLogo"        "True"
        Option          "ModeValidation" "NoDFPNativeResolutionCheck, NoMaxPClkCheck, NoHorizSyncCheck, NoVertRefreshCheck"
EndSection
```

The numbers in the `Modeline` line (from `109.00` onwards) should be replaced with the "Modeline" numbers that you obtain from running:

```
cvt <x-resolution> <y-resolution>
```

replacing `<x-resolution>` and `<y-resolution>` with the desired values. The two occurrences of `"1280x1024@60"` in the file can be changed to anything you'd like, so long as both of them are the same.

For the nouveau driver, remove the `Option` lines in `Section "Device"`, and change the value of `Driver` to `"nouveau"`. Note that the safest way of switching between nouveau/nvidia is to [un]install nvidia-current in addition to modifying xorg.conf.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the relevant [Ubuntu wiki - X/Config/Resolution](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution)

the relevant part for you starts at: [5. adding undetected resolutions](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution#Adding_undetected_resolutions)

Comment: the output of the glxinfo | grep render says:
direct rendering: Yes
OpenGL renderer string: Software rasterizer GL_EXT_vertex_array_bgra, GL_NV_conditional_render,

Comment: Did you only try to install the nvidia drivers manually or also with apt-get ? (if you didn't, please don't do so, just tell me.)

Comment: I installed them manually

Comment: please uninstall the nvidia drivers first: `sudo /usr/bin/nvidia-installer --uninstall` then try Kano's (the man behind the Kanotix distribution) script. you can get it [here](http://kanotix.org/files/install-nvidia-debian.sh). open a virtual terminal ctrl+alt+f1 and run the script as sudo.

Comment: ran the script - which apparently ran its length. Then screen went black, locked. I did a power shut down, started the pc - and now its stuck in the purple screen again

Comment: please post the contents of /var/log/Xorg.0.log. (use pastebin - http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/ )

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, changed to HDMI and it worked, check this thread if you can get some more info [14-04-lts-unknown-display-1024x768-only](https://askubuntu.com/questions/695519/14-04-lts-unknown-display-1024x768-only/793057#793057)