# Ubuntu loads Unity 2D rather than Unity 3D

Tags: unity

At the login screen of my Ubuntu box, I select Ubuntu under the cog menu, but it loads the 2D version instead of the 3D version.

I'm running:

- Asus P5Q Pro
- Intel Core 2 Quad Q6600 @ 2.40GHz x4
- GeForce 9600GT (1024MB)
- 32-bit OS
- 4x 1GB DDR2 RAM Modules (although BIOS only shows I'm using ~3GB)

Is this setup not capable of running Unity 3D? I understand that it won't install it if it's not supported!

**unity_support_test** output:

```
penGL vendor string:   NVIDIA Corporation
OpenGL renderer string: GeForce 9600 GT/PCI/SSE2
OpenGL version string:  3.3.0 NVIDIA 290.10

Not software rendered:    yes
Not blacklisted:          yes
GLX fbconfig:             yes
GLX texture from pixmap:  yes
GL npot or rect textures: yes
GL vertex program:        yes
GL fragment program:      yes
GL vertex buffer object:  yes
GL framebuffer object:    yes
GL version is 1.4+:       yes

Unity 3D supported:       yes
```

**glxinfo** output after driver reinstall:

```
direct rendering: Yes
    GL_NV_path_rendering, GL_NV_pixel_data_range, GL_NV_point_sprite, 

direct rendering: Yes
    GL_NV_path_rendering, GL_NV_pixel_data_range, GL_NV_point_sprite,
```

Comment: run this comand and check if your graphics can support unity or not `/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p`.

Comment: I get a 'Segmentation fault' when I run that command....

Comment: What is the output of this: `sudo jockey-text --list`

Comment: usually the problems occur when openGL support does not work. Please check the output of glxinfo | grep rendering - there should appear "direct rendering: yes" - further you can test opengl-support with glxgears. Then you should see rotating gears. If one of this does not wort, reinstall your graphics driver. I suggest to install the proprietary Nvidia driver as I described here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/80121/525-m-nvidia-grapic-card-is-not-work-in-linux

Comment: @heartsmagic output is: kmod:nvidia_current_updates - NVIDIA binary Xorg driver, kernel module and VDPAU library (Proprietary, Disabled, Not in use)
kmod:nvidia_173 - NVIDIA binary Xorg driver, kernel module and VDPAU library (Proprietary, Disabled, Not in use)
kmod:nvidia_173_updates - NVIDIA binary Xorg driver, kernel module and VDPAU library (Proprietary, Disabled, Not in use)
kmod:nvidia_current - nvidia_current (Proprietary, Enabled, Not in use) -- I tried to install nvidia latest driver and now have x server issues!

Comment: You can remove the installed driver and start the X server again. I don't know what was the error but somehow your card could be incompatible with latest drivers. You can try the others maybe.

Comment: @neildeadman Can you put the glxinfo and all that stuff in your question so it doesn't get buried in the comments?

Comment: @neildeadman - so now that you've installed the graphics drivers - does Unity 3D now work?

Comment: Partially, I get the Unity 3D display but one screen is white! Guess that is a different issue though.... How do I accept an answer for this Q?

Comment: Screen white? If you have an answer, just write what you have done so far, and accept it yourself.

Comment: I have two screens... The main one loads Unity or does when Compiz is installed, but the other one is pure white. Without compiz, I can move stuff over to it and use it etc (but no panel at top). With compiz the mouse cursor changes to a black X and it is totally unusable!

Comment: Sorry, I am not so exprienced for multple screens. But I think this is a different problem.

Comment: @neildeadman - your dual screen white problem is a different issue.  Create another question for this - add to that question what you have tried using the nvidia-xconfig app to configure dual screens.

Comment: @MichaelK Please answer this with your tip on re-installing drivers and I will mark it as the answer as that solved the problem! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

*Answer from a comment to the question:*

> Usually the problems occur when openGL support does not work. Please
>   check the output of `glxinfo | grep rendering` - there should appear
>   **direct rendering: yes** - further you can test `opengl-support` with `glxgears`. Then you should see rotating gears. If one of this does
>   not wort, reinstall your graphics driver. I suggest to install the
>   proprietary Nvidia driver as I described [here in this
>   question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80121/525-m-nvidia-grapic-card-is-not-work-in-linux)